Bootstrap 4.3 not mobile first
I am building a bootstrap component to drop into a clients site. They are still using Bootstrap 4.3. Bootstrap is supposed to be mobile first but when I inspect my dev site, it is calling the .col-md class instead of .col-6 class that I have first. When I inspect and choose device view, it doesn't collapse and stack like it's supposed to.
The buttons should be 6 columns each on mobile, then once it gets to medium size (768px)they should just space out evenly, but they don't.


<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <style>
    .renewable-calc {
      padding-top: 2%;
    }
    
    .btn-primary.ce-button {
      width: 100%;
      height: 48px;
      padding: auto;
      border: 4px solid #0079c1;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: transparent;
      color: #0079c1;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .btn-primary.ce-button:hover,
    .btn-primary.ce-button:active {
      background: #0079c1;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: pointer !important;
    }
    
    .is-active {
      background: #0079c1 !important;
      border-radius: 5px !important;
      color: #ffffff !important;
      font-weight: bold !important;
    }
    
    .boxed-in {
      background: #f5f5f5;
      border-radius: 14px;
      padding: 25px 30px;
    }
    
    input.numbers {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 48px;
      border: 1px solid #cccccd;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .green-icon {
      color: #639D36;
      font-size: 84px;
    }
    
    .green-text {
      color: #639D36;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 28px;
    }
    
    .blue-result-text {
      color: #0079C1;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    .gray {
      color: #929292;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container renewable-calc">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="heading">
            <h5>Percentage of renewable energy used</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row selectors d-flex justify-content-space-between" id="rc-button-bar">
          <div class="col-6 col-md mb-2">
            <button id="btn-25" class="btn-primary ce-button" data-value="25">25%</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md mb-2">
            <button id="btn-50" class="btn-primary ce-button" data-value="50">50%</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md mb-2">
            <button id="btn-85" class="btn-primary ce-button is-active" data-value="85">85%</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md mb-2">
            <button id="btn-100" class="btn-primary ce-button" data-value="100">100%</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
            <input id="customPercent" class="numbers" type="text" placeholder="ex: 80"></input>&nbsp;<span class="boldtxt">%</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-5 text-center">
      <div class="col">
        <h4>Greenhouse Gas Reduction (Yearly Equivalent) <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This will have an explanation"><i class="fa fa-info-circle gray"></i></a> </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3 boxed-in text-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
            <i class="fa fa-tree green-icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
            <h6>Equal to planting</h6>
            <span class="green-text"><span id="rc-tree">{ }</span> Trees</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
            <i class="fa fa-car green-icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
            <h6>Equal to removing</h6>
            <span class="green-text"><span id="rc-car">{ }</span> Cars</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
            <i class="fa fa-recycle green-icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
            <h6>Equal to recycling</h6>
            <span class="green-text"><span id="rc-recycle">{ }</span> tons of trash</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-5 text-center">
      <div class="col">
        <h4>Typical Monthly Cost <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This will have an explanation"><i class="fa fa-info-circle gray"></i></a></h4>
        <span class="blue-result-text">~$<span id="monthly-cost">{ }</span></span>
        <h5>per month</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })

    //the calculator variables for the button bar
    // let renewCalc = document.getElementById("rc-button-bar");
    let twentyFive = document.getElementById("btn-25");
    let fifty = document.getElementById("btn-50");
    let eightyFive = document.getElementById("btn-85");
    let oneHundred = document.getElementById("btn-100");
    let treeOutput = document.getElementById("rc-tree");
    let carOutput = document.getElementById("rc-car");
    let recycleOutput = document.getElementById("rc-recycle");
    let monthlyCost = document.getElementById("monthly-cost");


    treeOutput.innerHTML = "100";
    carOutput.innerHTML = "5";
    recycleOutput.innerHTML = "0.5";
    monthlyCost.innerHTML = "12.89";

    twentyFive.addEventListener("click", function() {
      treeOutput.innerHTML = "10",
        carOutput.innerHTML = "0.5",
        recycleOutput.innerHTML = "0.1",
        monthlyCost.innerHTML = "4.33";
    })

    fifty.addEventListener("click", function() {
      treeOutput.innerHTML = "45",
        carOutput.innerHTML = "2",
        recycleOutput.innerHTML = "0.244",
        monthlyCost.innerHTML = "7.95";
    })
    eightyFive.addEventListener("click", function() {
      treeOutput.innerHTML = "100",
        carOutput.innerHTML = "5",
        recycleOutput.innerHTML = "0.5",
        monthlyCost.innerHTML = "12.89";
    })
    oneHundred.addEventListener("click", function() {
      treeOutput.innerHTML = "140",
        carOutput.innerHTML = "9",
        recycleOutput.innerHTML = "0.98",
        monthlyCost.innerHTML = "17.50";
    })

    var btnContainer = document.getElementById("rc-button-bar");
    var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("ce-button");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        (document.querySelector('.is-active')) ? document.querySelector('.is-active').classList.remove('is-active'): '';
        this.classList.add('is-active');
      });
    }
  </script>




Please don't send us to other sites. See [ask]. Revise the demo above as needed to show your problem.

FYI, input elements are self-closing. It's invalid to include a closing tag.

Running the snippet here, it works as you would expect it to. Do you have something else potentially overriding the BS classes?

updated the code to show the entire document because @isherwood said it's the only way to get help. I don't see anything that is overriding the BS code.

The demo above with your code (take a closer look at the editor so you can do that yourself) works as you describe. So does your original page, by the way. I'm really not sure what you need.

I looked at it on my phone and it didn't stack, just shrunk everything and kept same layout. When I inspect it shows
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-md {
-ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
flex-basis: 0;
-ms-flex-positive: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
max-width: 100%;
}

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469972/bootstrap-not-scaling-properly-on-mobile-devices

added the viewport metatag and it fixed the layout issue.
